# Hiding app icons in 'All' menu

Tags: 16.04

Java's installation added six icons to my app menu, which are rather annoying to see every time I open my app launcher menu. Is there any way to hide these icons? Any information would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For achieving that you simply have to remove them from `/usr/share/applications`. Do do so open a terminal (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>) and navigate to said directory by:

```
cd /usr/share/applications
```

There find the corresponding `.desktop` files and remove them (I highly recommend you take them somewhere else for backing them up, otherwise they will be gone forever and you might need to do a complete remove and new install to get them back), nevertheless heres the command for removing them:

```
sudo rm <application>.desktop
```

If you want to move them instead use this command:

```
sudo mv <application>.desktop /path-to-a-backup-folder/
```

**Note: You will have to reboot to make those changes take effect**

Comment: Just to be clear, the .desktop files are just the launchers, right? Removing them won't delete the programs, just remove them from the launcher menu?

Comment: They are only the link files, not the application itself.

Answer (score 4):

To *hide* icons from the launcher without deleting/moving the launcher icon follow these steps:

1. Find the `.desktop` file of interest in: ***~/.local/share/applications*** for current user or ***/usr/share/applications*** for all users.
2. Open the file in text editor and add this entry to the file:

   ```
   NoDisplay=True
   ```

   or simply run

   ```sh
   echo "NoDisplay=true" | tee /absolute/path/of/filename.desktop   #For single file
   echo "NoDisplay=true" | tee -a /absolute/path/of/{filenames_separated_by_comma(,)}.desktop   #For multiple files
   ```

Source: [GNOME Desktop Entry Specification](https://developer.gnome.org/desktop-entry-spec/)